# Ruby - Finding if any two numbers in an array if multiplied equal to a third number

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an interesting problem. Given an array, I would like to find out if there are any two numbers in that array that if multiplied together equal a third number `n`

I would print true to the console if there was and false if there wasn't

Example

```
array = [4,7,9,13]
n = 63
```

This would return true since `9 * 7 = 63`

```
def multiply_to (array, n)
  if array.any?(2){|a,b| a * b == n}
    puts "true"
  else
    puts "false"
  end
end
```

I am a newcomer to `Ruby`, but this code doesn't work. Where did I go wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a note on optimization: you can first create a sub array of numbers that are possible candidates by checking that  n % a == 0, and then run your algorithm on the subarray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to show a slightly more complicated version

```
def multiply_to (array,n)
  numbers = array.map{|x|[x]}
  pairs = []

  for i in 0..numbers.length-1
    pairs.concat numbers[i].product(array - numbers[i])
  end

  puts "#{pairs.count{|a,b|a * b == n} > 0}"

end
```

In languages that do not offer the functionality of Ruby, you need to do a little work.

We can store our combos in an array called `pairs`

We'd like to iterate over every number in the array. For all those numbers, we want to take the product of an array with that element and all the other numbers of the array.

This gives us all our combos of two numbers. We can test this method out as follows

```
multiply_to([4,7,9,13], 63)
=> true
```

Answer (score 4):

You could write it:

```
def multiply_to(array, n)
  array.combination(2).any? { |a,b| a * b == n }
end

array = [4,7,9,13]
n = 63
puts multiply_to array, n
# >> true

array = [4,7,91,13]
n = 63
puts multiply_to array, n
# >> false
```

[`#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) doesn't take any argument, but you passed it the argument. So you got the valid error :

```
# `any?': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: `if else end`, hm? just `puts array.combination(2).any? { |a,b| a * b == n }`

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov I got blind for sometime. :;)

Answer (score 0):

We are given an array of numbers `arr` and a target product `n`.  You didn't say whether `arr` contained only integers, and if so, whether the integers must be non-negative.  Based in part on your example, I will make both of those assumptions, but the approach can be modified to handle some changes to the assumptions.

I will suggest a solution that should be relatively efficient. The benchmark is using brute-force, which requires up to `n*n` multiplications and comparisons.

I believe all of the following operations are linear in `n`.

First, if `n = 0`, we require that `arr` contain at least two elements, with at least one being a zero:

```
(arr.size > 1 && arr.index(0)) if n.zero?
```

If `n > 0` and `n` is a perfect square, we require it's square root to appear at least twice in `arr`:

```
sqrt = f(n)
arr.count(sqrt) > 1
```

There are very fast ways to calculate integer square roots, (or conclude one does not exist), such as [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root).

Next, create a set containing the unique elements of `arr` that are factors of `n`:

```
require 'set'
sarru = arr.each_with_object(Set.new) { |e,s| s << e if n%e == 0 }
```

and an array of those elements:

```
arru = sarru.to_a
```

Lastly, step through `arru` and check if the set `sarru` contains the complementary factor, `n/e` (which is very fast):

```
factor = arru.find { |e| sarru.include?(n/e) }
```

We then return:

```
factor ? [factor, n/factor] : nil
```